# How do I add a Calculated [bit] Data Type field to a SQL Table?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcommand

I would like to add a [bit] field that is calculated from a Boolean [int] field

SQL Table looks as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AutoIndexBoolean](
    [RowID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Boolean] [int] NULL,
    [BooleanCalc2] AS (case when [Boolean]=(0) then 'False' when [Boolean]=(1) then 'True'  end),
```

SQL Query to add column looks as follow:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AutoIndexBoolean]
ADD [BooleanBit] [bit] AS (CASE WHEN [Boolean]=(0) THEN '0' WHEN [Boolean]=(1) THEN '1' END)
```

As soon as I specify the DataType "[bit]", the AS turns into a Syntax error.

How do I add a Calculated [bit] field into my table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value returned from the `CASE` expression. You could likely do this as short as the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.AutoIndexBoolean 
    ADD BooleanBit AS TRY_CONVERT(bit,Boolean);
```

If your column `Boolean` can have other values that `1`, or `0` then do something like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.AutoIndexBoolean 
    ADD BooleanBit AS CONVERT(bit, CASE Boolean WHEN 0 THEN 0 WHEN 1 THEN 1 END);
```

Of course, the *real* solution would seem to be change your column `Boolean` to be a `bit`, and then you don't need a second column at all.

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the prompt response.

I am trying to update a [bit] field with an external programm, but the programm doesnt see/allow me to update a [bit] field. Thus my idea is to let SQL update the [bit] field from a [int] field that is seen/allowed to be edited by the external program.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), @Evan , and you should really eb asking about how to fix your application to reference a `bit` column.

Comment: Sounds weird but I think it's better to cast twice on the inside of the `CASE` than once on the outside. Otherwise it seems you get a `CONVERT` in the execution plan, whereas converting on the inside means it transforms it into a `bit` constant

Comment: @Larnu, unfortunatly I do not have the power to make changes on the Application that I am using. I can only hope that they will add the feature to a future update. Thanks for your advice